# Redraw solely a specific axes object in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, draw, axes

I am trying to code a small video game in Python with matplotlib exclusively. The idea is to have a character on a small axes object which is moving on a larger map. I managed to update the location of the axes but the method seems to redraw the full figure instead of the small axes object (by calling plt.draw() in the source code), therefore the heavy map behind the character as well, making the process extremely slow.

Is there any way to redraw a specific axes object in matplotlib ?

I am working in an IPython shell of a terminal.

Here is a test code simulating my problem where I obtain something 10 times slower than the ideal case :

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt 
import time
import numpy as np 

dtframe = 0.02 #time between plot updating in seconds
frames = 30

plt.subplots(5,5) #to simulate an heavy background matplotlib figure 
ax = plt.axes([0.1,0.5,0.03,0.03])
plt.show(block=False)

begin = time.time()
for j in np.linspace(0.1,0.9,frames):
    plt.pause(dtframe)
    ax.set_position([j,0.5,0.03,0.03])
    #ax.set_position([j,0.5,0.03,0.03], redraw_only_axes=True) ???

print('Current time [s] :',time.time() - begin)
print('Expected time [s] :',dtframe*frames)

#Current time [s] : 5.70146918296814
#Expected time [s] : 0.6
```

Answer (score 1):

The technique you are looking for is called blitting.

There is a tutorial on doing this in matplotlib here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/blitting.html

Comment: Thanks you for that help ! However by looking the example it seems that blitting is more dedicated to update the artist object inside an axes that the axes itself or am I wrong ? I don't see how to adapt the example that you provided to my case...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tutorial provided by @ianhi, here is the solution with blitting :

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt 
import time
import numpy as np 

dtframe = 0.02 #time between plot updating in seconds
frames = 30

fig,axes = plt.subplots(5,5) #to simulate an heavy background matplotlib figure 
ax = plt.axes([0.1,0.5,0.03,0.03],animated=True)
plt.show(block=False)
plt.pause(0.1)

bg = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(fig.bbox)
fig.canvas.blit(fig.bbox)

begin = time.time()
for j in np.linspace(0.1,0.9,frames):
    fig.canvas.restore_region(bg)
    ax.set_position([j,0.5,0.03,0.03])
    plt.pause(dtframe)
    fig.draw_artist(ax)
    fig.canvas.blit(fig.bbox)
    fig.canvas.flush_events()

print('Current time [s] :',time.time() - begin)
print('Expected time [s] :',dtframe*frames)

#Current time [s] : 1.2531671524047852
#Expected time [s] : 0.6
```

Comment: You should just blit using `ax.bbox` to get better performance. Currently you are blitting the entire figure

Comment: @Ianhi If I replace all the fig.bbox by ax.bbox I obtain several duplicates of the axes which is moving.

Comment: oooh yeah, you need to blit two positions. The bbox prior to moving the axes and the bbox after